# Empty bar chart matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to create a bar chart using the following two arrays - xbinmids as the x-coordinate and xbinned_ms as the height of the bar.

```
xbinned_ms:  [6.28e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.28e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.28e-16]

xbinmids:  [1.9869553456140592e-26, 5.960866036842178e-26, 9.934776728070296e-26, 1.3908687419298414e-25, 1.7882598110526532e-25, 2.185650880175465e-25, 2.583041949298277e-25, 2.9804330184210885e-25, 3.377824087543901e-25, 3.7752151566667126e-25, 4.172606225789524e-25, 4.569997294912336e-25, 4.967388364035148e-25, 5.36477943315796e-25, 5.762170502280771e-25, 6.159561571403584e-25, 6.556952640526395e-25, 6.954343709649207e-25, 7.351734778772019e-25, 7.749125847894831e-25, 8.146516917017643e-25, 8.543907986140454e-25, 8.941299055263266e-25, 9.338690124386079e-25, 9.73608119350889e-25, 1.0133472262631701e-24, 1.0530863331754513e-24, 1.0928254400877326e-24, 1.1325645470000137e-24, 1.1723036539122949e-24, 1.2120427608245762e-24, 1.2517818677368573e-24, 1.2915209746491384e-24, 1.3312600815614196e-24, 1.3709991884737009e-24, 1.410738295385982e-24, 1.4504774022982631e-24, 1.4902165092105445e-24, 1.5299556161228256e-24, 1.5696947230351067e-24, 1.6094338299473879e-24, 1.6491729368596692e-24, 1.6889120437719503e-24, 1.7286511506842314e-24, 1.7683902575965126e-24, 1.8081293645087937e-24, 1.8478684714210752e-24, 1.8876075783333563e-24, 1.9273466852456375e-24, 1.9670857921579186e-24, 2.0068248990701997e-24]
```

When I plot these arrays using:

```
xlow = 0
xhigh = 2.0068248990701997e-24
figMassxHist = plt.figure()
axMassxHist = plt.axes()
axMassxHist.set_xlim([xlow, xhigh])
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0, 0))

plt.bar(xbinmids, xbinned_ms, align='center')
```

the resulting bar plot is empty. I thought perhaps the bars were too thin to see and so tried to save the plot using:

```
plt.savefig(gdir + "/m_x_pp.eps", format='eps', dpi = 72*5)
```

but the result was still empty. How can I create a non-empty bar chart of this data?

Answer (score 1):

`plt.bar` has a `width` parameter that either can be a single width for all bars, or an array of widths for each individual bar. In this case, the difference between the first two x-values can be used, as all bins seem to have the same width. (If you need a little gap between the bars, you can multiply that number by 0.8 or so.)

`plt.bar` seems to do something wrong when the heights are extremely small. The ylims get messed up (setting them between -1e12 and 1e12), visualizing the bars too small to be visible. This error can be solved by explicitly setting the y-limits:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xbinned_ms =  [6.28e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.28e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.28e-16]
xbinmids = [1.9869553456140592e-26, 5.960866036842178e-26, 9.934776728070296e-26, 1.3908687419298414e-25, 1.7882598110526532e-25, 2.185650880175465e-25, 2.583041949298277e-25, 2.9804330184210885e-25, 3.377824087543901e-25, 3.7752151566667126e-25, 4.172606225789524e-25, 4.569997294912336e-25, 4.967388364035148e-25, 5.36477943315796e-25, 5.762170502280771e-25, 6.159561571403584e-25, 6.556952640526395e-25, 6.954343709649207e-25, 7.351734778772019e-25, 7.749125847894831e-25, 8.146516917017643e-25, 8.543907986140454e-25, 8.941299055263266e-25, 9.338690124386079e-25, 9.73608119350889e-25, 1.0133472262631701e-24, 1.0530863331754513e-24, 1.0928254400877326e-24, 1.1325645470000137e-24, 1.1723036539122949e-24, 1.2120427608245762e-24, 1.2517818677368573e-24, 1.2915209746491384e-24, 1.3312600815614196e-24, 1.3709991884737009e-24, 1.410738295385982e-24, 1.4504774022982631e-24, 1.4902165092105445e-24, 1.5299556161228256e-24, 1.5696947230351067e-24, 1.6094338299473879e-24, 1.6491729368596692e-24, 1.6889120437719503e-24, 1.7286511506842314e-24, 1.7683902575965126e-24, 1.8081293645087937e-24, 1.8478684714210752e-24, 1.8876075783333563e-24, 1.9273466852456375e-24, 1.9670857921579186e-24, 2.0068248990701997e-24]

plt.bar(xbinmids, xbinned_ms, width=xbinmids[1]-xbinmids[0], ec='k', lw=1)
plt.xlabel('bins')
plt.ylabel('ms')
plt.ylim(0, max(xbinned_ms)*1.1)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a bar graph can be plotted from your data, but other graphs such as scatter graphs (see code below) can be used. Hope its okay:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xbinned_ms =  [6.28e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.28e-16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.28e-16]

xbinmids = [1.9869553456140592e-26, 5.960866036842178e-26, 9.934776728070296e-26, 1.3908687419298414e-25, 1.7882598110526532e-25, 2.185650880175465e-25, 2.583041949298277e-25, 2.9804330184210885e-25, 3.377824087543901e-25, 3.7752151566667126e-25, 4.172606225789524e-25, 4.569997294912336e-25, 4.967388364035148e-25, 5.36477943315796e-25, 5.762170502280771e-25, 6.159561571403584e-25, 6.556952640526395e-25, 6.954343709649207e-25, 7.351734778772019e-25, 7.749125847894831e-25, 8.146516917017643e-25, 8.543907986140454e-25, 8.941299055263266e-25, 9.338690124386079e-25, 9.73608119350889e-25, 1.0133472262631701e-24, 1.0530863331754513e-24, 1.0928254400877326e-24, 1.1325645470000137e-24, 1.1723036539122949e-24, 1.2120427608245762e-24, 1.2517818677368573e-24, 1.2915209746491384e-24, 1.3312600815614196e-24, 1.3709991884737009e-24, 1.410738295385982e-24, 1.4504774022982631e-24, 1.4902165092105445e-24, 1.5299556161228256e-24, 1.5696947230351067e-24, 1.6094338299473879e-24, 1.6491729368596692e-24, 1.6889120437719503e-24, 1.7286511506842314e-24, 1.7683902575965126e-24, 1.8081293645087937e-24, 1.8478684714210752e-24, 1.8876075783333563e-24, 1.9273466852456375e-24, 1.9670857921579186e-24, 2.0068248990701997e-24]

plt.scatter(xbinmids, xbinned_ms)

plt.show()

plt.savefig(gdir + "/m_x_pp.eps", format='eps', dpi = 72*5)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: A bar graph is necessary to compare simulation results with experimental data. Unfortunately other graph types, like scatter or stem, are not as useful. I understand that Python will create a default width (of 0.8) for bar plots when 2 arrays are input as I did, but this seems to be too narrow a bar for the number of bars in the range I'm trying to plot.